# Automatically add dependency to pom in intellij, when intellij detects an unknown class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Ultimate 14.

When I try to use a class that isn't in a library listed as a dependency of the current project in its pom, Intellij will try to find a library that contains such a class and prompt you to add it to the classpath.

If you do, the import will appear to work for a while, but the dependency will not be added to the pom and so when building outside of intellij or re-importing maven changes, the import will stop working.

Is it possible to change the behavior of "add to classpath" so that intellij might also update the pom accordingly?

Comment: That would be difficult to do in many cases considering many dependencies have multiple versions available. So, how would Intellij decide which to use automatically?

Comment: But intelloj actually prompts you which jar you want! It also usually suggests the two last minor release versions of the same group and artifact. The problem isn't finding the jar in the first place.

Comment: Gotcha, I skimmed past "add to classpath" and was thinking about a different way which doesn't limit it to only two versions. If when you get the error you choose "Add Maven Dependency..." it will open a dialogue which allows you to search for artifact or class. Doing it this way adds it to the pom and classpath. It's not as quick but does the job correctly.